# Installed A new Version of Eclipse and altered the settings

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

I previously Have eclipse indigo, everything seems to look good, but when I deleted it and installed a new Eclipse(Eclipse Juno) it altered the font colors of .HTML and ,.JSP files how can I return it back ? the font color of jsp and .html files looks something like this

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can export settings in `indigo` and import them into `Juno`.

Comment: It looks like you're running a custom look and feel check out the preferences and change it. Also, Eclipse Color Theme is a great tool (marketplace) that is an easy way to deal with managing it consistently. I use a dark theme for coding (windows 7 Placebo Black Market 2 + Eclipse Color Theme) for an all black IDE/Light text. You may need to force eclipse into "classic" look and feel to get rid of the new tab styles.